# Typescript class can only be found if there isn't a reference to its properties?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am using TypeScript 2.0 in VSCode, however, the errors highlighted are all confirmed by the TypeScript compiler. So I am importing a module:

```
import * as els from 'elasticsearch';
```

where `elasticsearch` has definitions installed, e.g. *`npm i @types/elasticsearch -S`*

Now if in my class I have a property with an els type like this:

```
private _client: els.Client;
```

There isn't an issue, however, if I have a property with a type like this:

```
search(term: string): Promise<els.Client.search> {}
```

then I get the error:

> Module 'Elasticsearch' has no exported member 'Client'

[image]

How can the class not be found if I'm looking for one of its properties, but not if I just look for it?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the error message is confusing. It originates from your attempt to use els.Client.search as a type. You get similar messages if you try this:

```
import * as els from 'elasticsearch';

class Foo {
    private _client: els.Client;

    y: els.Client.search;

    bar() {}

    x: Foo.bar;
}
```

> error TS2305: Module 'Elasticsearch' has no exported member 'Client'.
>
> error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'Foo'.

Note how in the second message it complains that it can't find `Foo` right within the `Foo` class. You might consider posting an issue for typescript about this.

> How can the class not be found if I'm looking for one of its
>   properties, but not if I just look for it?

The real problem is that you probably want the return type of your `search` to be the same as the return type of `els.Client.search`. I don't think there is a better way to do that other than essentially copy `els.Client.search` declaration:

```
search<T>(term: string): Promise<els.SearchResponse<T>> {}
```